# Convert NSString containing URL to POSIX path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nspathcontrol

I'm working on retrieving a POSIX path to a folder or file from an `NSPathControl` after dropping the file or folder onto it.

I'm a beginner, but I was able to get the value from the control (called `Destination`) in my code this way:

```
NSString *filepath;
filepath = [Destination stringValue];
```

This gives me something like

```
file://test/My%20New%20Project/
```

but I'd like to have it in the POSIX path form:

```
/test/My New Project
```

because I need to pass it to a `NSTask` running a command-line program.

Any suggestion about how to convert the content of this `NSString` from an URL format to a POSIX path?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `-URL` instead of `-stringValue`. That will return an `NSURL` object representing the path displayed by the path control. You can then send `-path` to the `NSURL` object to obtain its string representation without the URL scheme/escaping. For instance:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [Destination URL];
NSString *filepath = [fileURL path];
```

or

```
NSString *filepath = [[Destination URL] path];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly Bavarious, thanks!! This website it's always really the only place on the internet for all programmers!